# using asp.net sqlmembership how do i send a user their password if password format is set to hashed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, forgot-password

setting type to hashed seems to not allow enablePasswordRetrieval.  what if a user forgot their password?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a hashed password is lost, the only option is to create a new one. Either by the user or by an administrator(-tool).

A common practice is to send a link to a secured page where the user can enter a new password.

Answer (score 1):

Hashes are not-reversible to their native form, which is why password recovery is not possible. If this is a requirement you will need to use encryption instead. To do this, change `passwordFormat="Hashed"` to `passwordFormat="Encrypted"`